# Can a Laravel Model target multiple Algolia indices with different attributes for each?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, algolia

I've been experimenting with the [algoliasearch-laravel](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel) package.

I see that it's possible for a Model to target multiple indices by using the `public $indices` array within in the model.

I also see it's possible to specify which attributes are sent to an index by using the `getAlgoliaRecord()` method.

My question is, is it possible for a single Model to send different attributes to different indices?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirements. A pull request is open to add this functionality [here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel-4/pull/6).

In the meantime, you can can simply update your `composer.json` to include the repository manually.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/lxrco/algoliasearch-laravel-4.git"
    }
],
```

And to use it, you'll have access to the indexName in your models `getAlgoliaRecord` method, like so:

```
public function getAlgoliaRecord($indexName)
{
    $extraData = [];

    if ($indexName === 'private_contacts') {
        $extraData = [
            'personal_number' => $this->personal_number,
            'home_address' => $this->home_address
        ];
    }

    return array_merge($this->toArray(), $extraData);
}
```